# Animate scroll between sections - without a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

Im trying to create a script that animates the scrolling between section on my page without using a plugin - just pure jquery. But seems that I'm experiencing some issues when I try and scroll my page. Can anyone help me?

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcDex/2/)
And my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.main').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
            var mHeight=$(document).height()/8;
            console.log(mHeight);
            if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
                // alert('up');
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: mHeight
                }, 1000);
            }
            else{
                // alert('down');
                $('html body').animate({
                    scrollTop: -mHeight
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @AnoopJoshi i want to animate and scroll between section not between something like this http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ but without a plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var mHeight = $(document).height() / 8;
        console.log(mHeight);
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
            // alert('up');
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: -mHeight
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            // alert('down');
            $('html body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: mHeight
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XcDex/3/)

**Edit**

```
 var index = 1;
    $('body').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var mHeight = $(document).height() / 8;
        console.log(mHeight);
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
            // alert('up');
            index--;
            mHeight = mHeight * index;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: mHeight
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            // alert('down');
            index++;
            mHeight = mHeight * index;
            $('html body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: mHeight
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XcDex/5/)

Comment: Any idea how can we detect the wheel/ execute the function only once per time - so only one section is changed?

Comment: i think, finish event of animation can help you. do a research on that